# Why event is binding to nested list items

Tags: jquery

Guys I'm facing a problem on click event. What I'm doing is there is `ul` with some `li's` also this `ul` is nested list. I bind a click event to list items that works fine, but why the same click event working with nested list items. How to cancel that event.

```js
$('.item').on('click',function(e){
  alert('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">Orange</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Magenta</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Brown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can prevent click on nested lists with something like this `if($(e.target).is('li ul *')) {e.preventDefault();return;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the click event gets propagated from the element to the parent element (and even further upwards until `document` is reached) - which btw is the only reason why your code works at all, because the click is being triggered on the anchor `a`, not on the list item `li.item` - and is propagated to the list item.

You can solve your specific problem by making your selector more specific:

```js
$('.item > a').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="itemlist">
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">Orange</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Magenta</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Brown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```